# multiple rules of URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine  On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html[L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /profile.php?name=$1
```

This is currently .htaccess of my website. The rewriting supposes to have two functions, makes the internal url example/profile.php/name=xyz into example/xyz as external url, and also removes the extensions of html files.

But the extension removing is not working, and such as for a file named xyz.html, it gets 404 and

```
example.com/xyz/?name=xyz
```

At the address bar. I think there is some conflicts between two rules.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule` hence your last rule is running without any `RewriteCond`. Also you need to use `[L]` (Last) flag in all of your rules.

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine  On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You have a typo on the second bracket on the last line, unfortunately I can't edit anything below 6 characters so I'll just leave a comment.